# Spring Boot JPA EntityListener query causes "don't flush the Session after an exception occurs"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, exception

**Problem:**

I create object A with an `EntityListener` with `@PostPersist`-method that will create object B, this works like a charm!
I need to introduce some logic before creating object B, I need to query the database and see if a similar B object already exists in the database. But when I run my query

```
@Query("select case when count(n) > 0 then true else false end from Notification n where student = :student and initiator = :initiator and entityType = :entityType and entityId = :entityId")
boolean alreadyNotified(@Param("student") Student student, @Param("initiator") Student initiator, @Param("entityType") EntityType entityType, @Param("entityId") Long entityId);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR org.hibernate.AssertionFailure.<init>(31) - HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in se.hitract.model.Likes entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in se.hitract.model.Likes entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

**Background:**
I have a Spring Boot project with Hibernate and MySql DB and I'm building a simple social media platform where students can upload posts/images and other user can like/comments.

When someone like/comment an object a notification should be sent to the other user. The like object:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"entityType", "entityId", "studentId"}))
@EntityListeners(LikeListener.class)
public class Likes extends CommonEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long likeId;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EntityType entityType;

    private Long entityId;

...

}
```

The LikeListener:

```
@Component
public class LikeListener {

    @PostPersist
    public void doThis(Likes like) {
        
        NotificationService notificationService = BeanUtil.getBean(NotificationService.class);
        
        if(like.getEntityType().equals(EntityType.INSPIRATION)) {
            InspirationService inspirationService = BeanUtil.getBean(InspirationService.class);
            Inspiration inspiration = inspirationService.get(like.getEntityId());
            notificationService.createLikeNotification(inspiration.getStudent(), like.getStudent(), EntityType.INSPIRATION, inspiration.getId());
        }
        if(like.getEntityType().equals(EntityType.COMMENT)) {
            CommentService commentService = BeanUtil.getBean(CommentService.class);
            Comment comment = commentService.get(like.getEntityId());
            notificationService.createLikeNotification(comment.getStudent(), like.getStudent(), EntityType.COMMENT, comment.getId());
        }   
    }
}
```

and the problem:

```
public Notification createLikeNotification(Student student, Student initiator, EntityType entityType, Long entityId) {
    if(student.equals(initiator) || alreadyNotified(student, initiator, entityType, entityId)) {
        return null;
    }
    
    Notification notification = createNotification(student,
            initiator,
            NOTIFICATION_TYPE.LIKE,
            entityType,
            entityId,
            null);

    return repository.save(notification);
}

public boolean alreadyNotified(Student student, Student initiator, EntityType entityType, Long entityId) {
    return repository.alreadyNotified(student, initiator, entityType, entityId);
}
```

If I remove the `alreadyNotified`-call no error is thrown. What am I missing?
It seems that Hibernate flushes the Likes-save before my query is run but then it fails. Do I need to do some manual flush/refresh? I think Hibernate should solve this for me.

Comment: See the [JPA Spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1604258065_687de4c6b794ed63c0f49799cd0d4c89), section 3.5.2: 'In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
same persistence context'.

Comment: Just curious, what did you end up doing here? I have the same exact problem.